# SonarLint for Eclipse Oxygen : Not able to see SonarQube server tab

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint, eclipse-oxygen, sonarlint-eclipse

I tried all possible way to view `SonarQube` Server tab, but couldn't get succeed with same.

Tried all below:

1. Window -> Show View -> Other -> SonarLint
   [Show View Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meomT.png)
2. Right Click on Project -> SonarLint -> Analyse
   [Refer Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3acJV.png)

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Any error in Eclipse logs?

Comment: This si working fine for me using

Comment: The "SonarQube Servers" tab is working fine for me using Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a). If you are not on that version it might be worth upgrading Eclipse, and trying again. Also, as Julien suggested, select Window->Show View->Error Log to see if there are any errors for the Sonar Lint plugin. Finally, the version of the SonarLint plugin that works for me is 3.2.0.201706271328.